# How to pass an unspecified number of argument to a js function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to pass multiples arguments to a function. The thing is, the amount of arguments varies depending of the situation. This function is meant to add elements to a listview (with Kendo UI) and I don't know how to handle that in JS

So basically, in the docs, the say, if we want to add 2 elements to the list, this is how it should look like.

```
var removed = sports.splice(1, 1, "tennis", "hockey");
```

I have to pass every argument one by one into the function. I can't do this when I do not know the exact number of argument.
For each element I receive from my server, I need to insert it into the splice method.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ )
{
        // add one more parameter to splice method
};

// in order to have something like this:
var removed = sports.splice(0, 0, result[0], result[1], ....,result[lastOne] );
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on the `splice` function, which allows you to specify the arguments as an array:

```
var removed = sports.splice.apply( sports, [0, 0].concat(result) );
```

But if `sports` is an standard array (or otherwise provides an equivalent to the standard [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method), you could also do this:

```
var newLength = sports.unshift.apply( sports, result );
```